# Checkbox doesn't stay checked, conten

Tags: php, loop

I'm using the morefields plugin to create textfields and checkboxes in the dashboard.
For a test I have first created a checkbox on 'pages' if it was checked, the frontend showed the text 'TESTCONTENT', if it wasn't it was showing 'GEEN CONTENT'.
It worked, so the code I used is working also.

Now I want to show an extra div in a custom-post-type loop containing a 'new' stamp , so I created a checkbox on the `projecten` (the name of my `CPT`.)

I gave this the value and field-key: `'newproject'`.

Now when I want to check my checkbox, I go to a project and turn the checkbox on, but when I update the project and look again, the checkbox turned itself off.
I can't figure it out, I thought maybe it is because I put a loop in a loop but I don't think it had something to do with the checkbox turning off.

This is my code of the whole loop (so, the loop in the loop)

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); //opening 1st loop?>
                <div class="extracontent-block">
                    <div class="extracontent-block-image">
                        <?php $newproject = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'newproject', true ); //checkbox?>
                            <?php if($newproject) { //if checkbox is checked?>
                                <div id="newblock">Nieuw</div><div class="stamp checked"><?php meta('project-text'); ?></div>
                            <?php } else { //if checkbox isn't checked?>
                                <div class="stamp"><?php meta('project-text'); ?></div>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <?php $featured = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "Full"); ?>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $featured[0]; ?>&amp;w=300&amp;h=200&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;" width="300" height="200" data-thumb="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $featured[0]; ?>&amp;w=300&amp;h=200&amp;zc=1&amp;q=100&amp;" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    </div><!--/extracontent-block-image-->
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="button"><?php meta('project-button'); ?></div></a>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**EDIT**

The loop is working, I just refreshed the page and one of the checkboxed was checked, with the effect I want.
Now, if I want to check one, they turn their-self off automatically again.